# C++ Split a string by blank spaces unless it is enclosed in quotes and store in a vector

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, split

I have a prompt that takes user input. I want to take this user input and store each word in a vector, splitting by a blank space, unless a group of words is contained between quotes, in which case I want all of the terms within the sections to count as 1.

For example, if the user enters the following:

```
12345 Hello World "This is a group"
```

Then I want the vector to store the following:

```
vector[0] = 12345
vector[1] = Hello
vector[3] = World
vector[4] = "This is a group"
```

I have the following code, which splits the user input by blank space and stores it in a vector, but I am having trouble figuring out how to make all text within quotes count as one.

```
 string userInput

 cout << "Enter a string: ";
 getline(cin, userInput);

string buf; 
stringstream ss(userInput); 

vector<string> input;

while (ss >> buf){
    input.push_back(buf);
```

I want to keep the quotes around the words where the user enters the passages. I also want to save the results to a vector rather than output the characters to the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    string str = "12345 Hello World \"This is a group\"";
    vector<string> v;
    size_t i = 0, j = 0, begin = 0;
    while(i < str.size()) {
        if(str[i] == ' ' || i == 0) {
            if(i + 1 < str.size() && str[i + 1] == '\"') {
                j = begin + 1;
                while(j < str.size() && str[j++] != '\"');
                v.push_back(std::string(str, begin, j - 1 - i));
                begin = j - 1;
                i = j - 1;
                continue;
            }

            j = begin + 1;
            while(j < str.size() && str[j++] != ' ');
            v.push_back(std::string(str, begin, j - 1 - i - (i ? 1 : 0) ));
            begin = j;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    for(auto& str: v)
        cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
12345
Hello
World
"This is a group"
```

However, notice that this code is for demonstration, since it doesn't handle all cases. For example, if yuo have onle double quote in your input, then this `while(j < str.size() && str[j++] != '\"');` will case the whole string from that point to not be splitted.

Comment: Welcome to c++14 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted

Comment: @gsamaras any idea why if I try something like `if v[1] == "Hello" ... do something` isn't working?

Comment: @MastRofDsastR `=` is for assignment, `==` if for comparisson. Did you miss that?

Comment: @gsamaras, apologies, meant `==`

Comment: I am not sure what are asking me @MastRofDsastR.

Comment: @gsamaras my purpose for storing the strings in a vector was to use certain strings in conditional statements. As mentioned, when I tried something along the lines of  `if v[I] == "Hello" ... do something` it did not enter the if statement

Comment: @MastRofDsastR that was because I was storing the trailing whitespace. I updated the code, now it works.

Comment: That code crashes when there are more than one whitespaces between the tokens or when there are trailing whitespaces.  To use it in real world applications (e.g. parse data files), a pre-processing of the input line would be necessary (e.g. trimming and removing double spaces).

Answer (score 9):

C++14 has it built in: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/168d98d81b2eb932)</kbd>**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(void) {
    std::istringstream iss("12345 Hello World \"This is a group\"");
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::string s;

    while (iss >> std::quoted(s)) {
        v.push_back(s);
    }

    for(auto& str: v)
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
12345
Hello
World
This is a group
```

Comment: I say that OP is misguided :) `std::quoted` can be used the other way too `std::cout << std::quoted("Whoah, that's \"cool\"!");`